# ssrs export to CSV including HTML code?

Tags: reporting-services, csv, report-builder2.0

I'm working on a report, using SSRS, that i want to export to multiple formats (excel, pdf, csv...)

When i'm trying to export to csv format, after the data values, it's including html code

why? can I override this behaviour with any change on the config file?

(my report includes only a table)

tks

Answer (score 0):

This not possible out of the box with SSRS.  The HTML renderer is a visual renderer, and the CSV renderer is designed to export just the data.  There's no way to get them to mix.

You would have to create a custom rendering extension to accomplish this goal.